# Direction of dependency connection

Tags: uml

I am new in uml. I have confusion about the direction of the dependency relationship. I mean what the arrow should point to?
Considering [this](http://www.sparxsystems.com.au/resources/tutorial/use_case_model.html) example, to access the **register book** you first need to **login**. My deduction says that  **register book** depends on **login**, so the arrow should point to login?

Answer (score 1):

Oh dear. You picked the worst example you could find.

A dependency in general points to the element from which the source is depending.

Now in that example they try to show how the `<<extends>>` for use cases works. This is intended to show that one use case optionally extends the functionality of another one. Now `Login` is not a use case at all. So extending it is not possible. If it were "do this and that" (I mean some real use case) the Register would extend "do this and that".